# Storing list of values from HTTP GET in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, jhipster

I am getting a list by calling the `$resource` URL from the controller, which is viewable in the logs.

**Controller**

```
function ClubDetailController($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $resource,
    DataUtils, entity, Club) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.club = entity;
    vm.byteSize = DataUtils.byteSize;
    vm.openFile = DataUtils.openFile;

    var Todo = $resource('api/club-inchargesByClubId/:clubId');
    var clubIncharges = [];

    vm.clubIncharges = Todo.get({clubId: $stateParams.id}).$promise;    
    clubIncharges = angular.fromJson(vm.clubIncharges);
    alert(clubIncharges);

})();
```

The problem is this list can't be stored in a var or object to be used later, for example this HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="clubIncharges in vm.clubIncharges track by clubIncharges.id">
```

I have also tried:

```
 var clubIncharges = [];
 clubIncharges = angular.fromJson(vm.clubIncharges);
```

And still couldn't get the expected output.

**Updated code**

```
   var clubIncharges = [];
    $http.get('api/club-            
   inchargesByClubId/'+$stateParams.id).then(function(response){
        alert(response.data);
        vm.clubIncharge = response.data;
        clubIncharges = angular.fromJson(vm.clubIncharge);
        vm.clubIncharges  = clubIncharges;
        alert(clubIncharges);
        console.dir(clubIncharges);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.error("Something went wrong!: " + error);
    });
```

The list from the DB logged:

```
 2016-10-15 13:41:22.985 DEBUG 3392 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] c.c.campuzz.aop.logging .LoggingAspect : Exit: com.campuz360.campuzz.web.rest.ClubInchargesResource.g 
 etClubInchargesByClubId() with result = [ClubIncharges{id=1, designaion='Chairma n', addedBy='null', clubId='2'}, ClubIncharges{id=2, designaion='bkujasrv', adde dBy='gawerg', clubId='2'}]
```

Latest edit

```
    $http.get('api/club-inchargesByClubId/' + $stateParams.id).then(function           (response) {
        $scope.club = response.data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Something went wrong!: " + error);
    });
```

Comment: Can you please console.log that list, edit your post, and show the output?

Comment: I saw this at end ")()". why are you calling your own controller ?

Comment: also if you are injecting $scope then try var vm = $scope; instead of var vm = this;

Comment: Tried, but same result.. :(

Comment: why are you using vm again in html? you should directly use <tr ng-repeat="clubIncharge in clubIncharges track by clubIncharges.id">

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `$http`, it is cleaner to me

```
function ClubDetailController($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $http,
DataUtils, entity, Club) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.club = entity;
    vm.byteSize = DataUtils.byteSize;
    vm.openFile = DataUtils.openFile;

    $http.get('api/club-inchargesByClubId/'+$stateParams.id).then(function(response){
        vm.clubIncharges = response.data;
        console.dir(vm.clubIncharges);
        clubIncharges = angular.fromJson(vm.clubIncharges);
        console.dir(clubIncharges);
    }).catch(function(error){
       console.error("Something went wrong!: " + error);
    }); 


})();
```

**EDIT**

The JSON response from the OP's API has an incorrect format. I recommend to use this tool to check for a correct JSON format: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: yeah, this time also i get the list as per logs. But in the alert message i can see only [object][object]. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Change `console.log` to `console.dir`

Comment: Nope i mean I have to store the retrieved list in a variable vm.clubIncharges so that i can use it in html as below.    **<tr ng-repeat="clubIncharges in vm.clubIncharges track by clubIncharges.id">**

Comment: do something like this:  $scope.promised = $http.get('api/club-inchargesByClubId/'+$stateParams.id);  $scope.promised.$promise.then(function(response){vm.clubInCharges...repeat that logic here})  Then in tr ng-repeat ng-show="promised.$resolved"

Comment: @Campuz360 can you post the object response you get?

Comment: 2016-10-15 13:41:22.985 DEBUG 3392 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] c.c.campuzz.aop.logging
.LoggingAspect    : Exit: com.campuz360.campuzz.web.rest.ClubInchargesResource.g
etClubInchargesByClubId() with result = [ClubIncharges{id=1, designaion='Chairma
n', addedBy='null', clubId='2'}, ClubIncharges{id=2, designaion='bkujasrv', adde
dBy='gawerg', clubId='2'}]

Comment: This is my response list. Please tell me how can i store in a var. I have edited my question with the latest code i have done.

Comment: @Campuz360 Put it in your question please, I am on mobile and it is difficult to see.

Comment: yeah added in question @distante

Comment: @Campuz360 Ok I see it now, your response is not correctly formatead, I am pretty sure is an error from the API you are using but how about remove the  `angular.fromJson` from your code?

Comment: Done removing the angular.fromJson part . code edited in question....Please have a look

Comment: Yes @distante.  :(

Comment: Then it is a problem from the Api side.

Comment: But i see expected list in the logs. If it is problem with API, then i should not get the result.

Comment: In which log? Do you mean inside `console.log`? Because it has an incorrect JSON format.

Comment: Nope in the debug log which i wrote in the java method

Comment: You can not have this `ClubIncharges{` that **ClubIncharges** is not allowed in  JSON

Comment: @Campuz360 try to do a get to this url: `https://api.github.com/users/distante/repos"` it has a correct JSON format. I use it in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Saninn/wnkcnjw6/  Also, you can use this tool to check your JSON https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: use route resolves, angular service to return actual data, NOT THE PROMISE (use .then() variant to resolve the promise).

Check this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XvA2O4xqcDWkmFWg0NPq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
Todo.get({clubId: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
```

is returning you promise not data.

You can refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
vm.clubIncharges = Todo.get({clubId: $stateParams.id});
```

Above line should work but it will not return data immediatly so your alert won't work. You can call get method like shown below to notify yourself when data is available.

```
vm.clubIncharges  = Todo.get({clubId: $stateParams.id}, function() {
  console.log(vm.clubIncharges);
});
```

and html should be

```
<tr ng-repeat="clubIncharge in clubIncharges track by clubIncharge.id">
```

Comment: Akshay, Thanks for your help but I dont want only to alert, My need is to store in a variable to be used in html

Comment: vm.clubIncharges = Todo.get({clubId: $stateParams.id}); this will store it in variable vm.clubIncharges, you need to make sure you are using that variable correctly